# How to get date and time separtely

Tags: angularjs, datetime, substr

I'm just a beginner of angularJs. I need to get only half value from input.

This is my code. I'm using datetime-picker

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Choose date and time" name="datetime" value="datetime" ng-model="date3.data" datetime-picker date-format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" close-on-select="false" />
```

Now I get `2016-06-29 12:14:00`

I need to separate date and time -like date = 2016-06-20 and time = 12:14:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `split` method in your string

```
t = "2016-06-29 12:14:00"
var a = t.split(" ");
var date = a[0];
var time = a[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

For getting the date and time separate , best way in angular is using the $filter

Please use below code

```
 $scope.time = $filter('date')($scope.date3.data, 'HH:mm:ss');

 $scope.date=$filter('date')($scope.date3.data, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

can change the format according to our requirement

Answer (score 1):

use this on your controller

for time

```
$scope.time = $filter('date')($scope.date3.data, 'HH:mm');
```

for date

```
$scope.date=$filter('date')($scope.date3.data, 'shortDate');
```

i think this is working for you

Answer (score 0):

Split the string by the space in the middle.

```
var dateString = "2013-09-01 16:20";
var split = dateString.split(s);
consol.log(split[0]+" at "+split[1]);
```